# Confidence intervals for Kendall's tau

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, nonparametric, kendall-tau

I am working on some stats coursework, and have non parametric bivariate data. n=19, so small sample. There are a number of tied ranks, so I'm planning to use Kendall's tau rather than Spearman's rho, as I have found some literature supporting this. My SPSS output has calculated tau = -.982, p <.001. What I have absolutely no idea of is how to calculate the confidence intervals. Am I correct in thinking I can't use the Fisher Z transformation with tau, and if so why not? Do I need to do something with bootstrapping (which I have never done!)? If anyone could help, in as basic terms as possible (very much a beginner!) I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have a basic understanding of how bootstrapping works (thank you youtube!) - I am just unsure if that is an appropriate way of calculating CIs for Kendall's tau-b

Answer (score 9):

[This paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/02626667.2011.586948) discusses the contexts where you can and can't use a normal approximation for Tau. According to Wikipedia, it also looks like the validity of normal/Z depends on how your version of Tau handles ties.  My sense is that it's probably safer not to assume that it's Gaussian, especially with relatively low sample sizes.

I couldn't think of a reason why Kendall's Tau wouldn't be compatible with the bootstrap, but I wasn't 100% sure. So I looked it up:

- [Here's a paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2669997.pdf) by Brad Efron, the inventor of the bootstrap, that uses it for Tau (Section 5).
- [Here's a paper](http://www3.stat.sinica.edu.tw/statistica/oldpdf/A10n410.pdf) that spends some time discussing the bootstrap in the context of Tau (mostly Section 4).

Looks like you shouldn't have any serious problems using the bootstrap for tau.

Comment: Very nice. Any idea of whether there's a better way than bootstrapping?

Comment: If we don't have tau's sampling distribution, the only alternatives I'm aware of are to approximate it (e.g. with a Gaussian) or to do some kind of resampling (like bootstrapping). This paper claims that the Gaussian approximation isn't too bad, and gives a formula for a Z-test (section 4). Keep in mind that the different options for handling ties will make a difference here.  https://www.utdallas.edu/~herve/Abdi-KendallCorrelation2007-pretty.pdf

Comment: (or, in a few words: bootstrapping is probably best, but it's not the only option)